# Unable to take screenshot in Percy with CSS

Tags: percy

Hi i am using Percy to take screenshot using below function

```
> await percySnapshot(t, 'Test Cafe Example6');
```

But it takes screenshot without ccs and assets being loaded.

Not sure what is going on.

[image]